# Distinguishing between a parabola and (one branch of) a hyperbola by looking at the graph

Tags: conic-sections

[image]

If I were to show you this curve that is quite zoomed in is it possible to tell if it is a hyperbola of a parabola

This is a picture my friend sent me and I cannot tell which conic section it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a hyperbola.

For $x > 4$, the gradients of the curve are nearly constant for both positive and negative values of $y$. This suggests it is approaching an asymptote, something which does not happen for a a parabola.

Answer (score 3):

Draw two or more parallel chords (not perpendicular to the axis). If their midpoints are aligned parallel to the axis, then it's a parabola. Otherwise it's a hyperbola and the intersection between the line of the midpoints and the axis is its center.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for this peculiar property or is it just something that "happens"

Comment: @JustJohan It is a property of any conic section and follows from this theorem: if $O$ is the centre of a conic (the centre of a parabola being at infinity) and $T$ a point on the conic, then line $OT$ meets all chords parallel to the tangent at $T$ at their midpoints. This can be proved in many different ways.